# how to save picture in Windows CE?

Tags: c#, windows-ce

i have Picturebox control that contain any picture  - on my form

how i can save this picture ?

in Windows-CE C#

thank's in advance

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
pictureBox.Image.Save(path, ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Comment: i got error: No overload for method 'Save' takes '1' arguments

Comment: @Gold: seriously, you couldn't figure that out?

Comment: Does the PictureBox have a picture?

Comment: you are right !! i only paint on the PictureBox... how to save this paint on picture box ?

Comment: You need to maintain a `Bitmap` object and draw everything on the `Bitmap` in addition to the `PictureBox`.

Comment: How, exeactly, are painting into the picturebox?  A little code works wonders for our understanding

Answer (score 0):

Well you've not given us much to go on at all, but I decided to try anyway.  This works fine for me:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            pictureBox1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(pictureBox1_Paint);
        }

        Bitmap m_cache;

        void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (m_cache == null)
            {
                m_cache = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
                var g = Graphics.FromImage(m_cache);
                g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.White), 
                                0, 0, m_cache.Width, m_cache.Height);
                g.DrawString("Hello World", this.Font, 
                             new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 0, 0);
            }

            e.Graphics.DrawImage(m_cache, 0, 0);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            m_cache.Save("\\myimage.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
    }
```

pictureBox1 is a PictureBox on Form1.

If this doesn't point you in the right direction, then you really need to post some code.